# Too big font size for user flagged post page

Tags: bug, design, flags, moderator-tools, fonts

Currently the font size on [user flagged posts page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flagged-posts/176217) is too big:

> [image]

It wasn't so big some times ago.

Looks like it affects many pages in user profile settings as well:

> [image]

> [image]